# MS Word - Change footnote/endnote icon to brackets with numbers

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using Word 2016. I have a Word document that contains multiple endnotes. I don't like the superscript number at all. It is way too hard to see. I want to change it to regular (non-superscript) text and make the symbols [1], [2], [3], and so on (similar to how Wikipedia does reference links). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplished as followed.

1. Press Ctrl+H to open the Find and Replace dialog box.
2. Put your cursor in the Find what box.
3. Click More, click Format, then Font. Select Superscript.

[image]

5. On the Replace by box, enter: `[^&]`.
6. Click Format, then Font. Remove Superscript and Subscript from the selection.
7. Click Format, then Styles. Select Normal.

[image]

The Find and Replace dialog box will look like this:

[image: IMG:]

8. Click replace all.

[image]